# Sql 2008 Debugging from Management Studio

Tags: sql, debugging, ssms, sql-server-2008-express

How do i attach debugger to Sql 2008 Express edition from Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

[How to: Debug Transact-SQL Using the SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241871%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: any ways thanks for the help. My issue has been resolved. But still if have any ggod links. Please post here.